# DataTable.js local storage json

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, local-storage

I'm trying to get the data stored on local storage and use that data in datatable...

**JSON DATA**

```
{
    "items": [{
        "id": "0",
        "itemcode": "/0002100ADAM",
        "desc": "No Problem Found",
        "price": "45.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "itemcode": "/0002100DIX-",
        "desc": "No Problem Found",
        "price": "45.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "itemcode": "/0009010BRN-",
        "desc": "Return with Part",
        "price": "50.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "itemcode": "/0009010DIX-",
        "desc": "Return with Part",
        "price": "50.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "itemcode": "/100-AA",
        "desc": "Standard Gadget",
        "price": "66.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "itemcode": "/1NOCLLLLDIXT",
        "desc": "No Charge Labor Code",
        "price": "55.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "itemcode": "/200-DA",
        "desc": "22\" Widget with Hinges",
        "price": "25.0000"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "itemcode": "/287-GA",
        "desc": "19\" Gadget with Wheels",
        "price": "75.0000"
    }],
    "state": true
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
  var restoredSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));

  $('#itemlookdata').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );

  $('#example').dataTable({
        aaData : restoredSession,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "id" },
            { "mData": "itemcode" },
            { "mData": "desc" },
            { "mData": "price" }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: what's not working? what have you tried? where are you stuck? (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: its not working and its not bringing any data to datatables and i always get the message that says No data available in table so i just want to know did i do anything wrong here ? is there any mistake in code! or anyone tried to get the data from local storage and placed data data into the datatables? and thank you for the link...

Comment: When and how do you store the JSON in localStorage?

Comment: @EdwinCa did you find sln for the problem??!! i know u couldnt phrase the qtn..same here.. So whats the update?!